# bulk_delete in mongodb using mongoid ruby

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongoid, bulk-delete

I have 10 million documents in a mongo collection as of current_date and want to destroy 6 million documents which are older than yesterday.

Is there any bulk_delete option in mongoid ? I know I can bulk_insert as 
`Mongo::my_collection.collection.insert(data)` which fires only one insert command.

Similarly is there any way to bulk_delete in mongoid?

Answer (score 0):

There is [deleteMany](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.deleteMany/) command, but despite it's a single command, the execution time may be huge and load on your database while deletion will be significant if not to say more.

I would write a script, which will slowly destroy records by reasonable chunks (ie. by 1000 of records per request).